# How do i split a string in a list then add it back into the list in the same position?

Tags: c#, list

I've been having trouble figuring this out, I'm trying to read a file but when i split the text I get "\r\n" at the end of each newline, making the string = "Example\r\nHello" instead of just: "Example", "Hello".

I have been able to replace "\r\n" with a space and add it into a list. But the strings don't seem to be replacing anything in the words list because the list doesn't change.

Here is my code:

```
        string textFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\example\Downloads\text.txt");
        List<string> words = new List<string>(textFile.Split(' '));

        foreach (var s in words)
        {
            if (s.ToLower().Contains('\n'))
            {
                var check = s.Replace("\r\n", " ");
                List<string> add = new List<string>(check.Split(' '));
                words.Concat(add);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "because the textfile doesn't change" ... It doesn't look like you write anything back to the text file, at least not in the code provided..

Comment: sorry my mistake, i've just made an edit, it was meant to be 'words list'
I want to make changes to words list after I have split the string that contained '\r\n'

Comment: I think this is overcomplicated. Just do the replace first, _then_ do the split.

Comment: I just want to split a string that doesn't contain "\r\n" so its like this: "hello" "hi" instead of "hello\r\nhi"

Comment: *words.Concat(add);* will not modify your List, but return a new IEnumerable with the concatenation of the two (which you are discarding), see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bronson, This may be a good place for some RegEx. How about:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string textFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\example\Downloads\text.txt");
var wdRx = new Regex(@"\W+");
List<string> words = new List<string>(wdRx.Split(txtFile));
foreach (var wd in words)
{
      Console.WriteLine(wd);
}
```

Which, if I understand your problem, would eliminate the need to strip out the new line characters. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Could you please explain to me what 'var wdRx = new Regex(@"\W+");' does? I've never used Regex before.

Comment: You bet, rather than tying to split the document by " ", Regex (@"\W+") splits the document by any group of "Word Characters", which has the effect of isolating the words in your document. To get a sense of how RegEx works, check out regex101.com, a truly awesome site.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyWords = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("")
    .myString.Replace("\r\n", " ")
    .Split(" ");
```

This seems like it will do what you need.